# IBM JSF Date Picker hx:inputHelperDatePicker Accessibility Issue

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, web-applications

I'm using the IBM *JSF* to build the application, and I found that there's a bug with the little calendar date picker component `hx:inputHelperDatePicker`, which is that the Date picker icons can **only** be accessible and opened once with a keyboard or mouse. The little calendar will only popup for the first time I click on the date picker icon, after that it would not be accessible any more. And here's the code:

```
import com.ibm.faces.component.html.HtmlInputHelperDatePicker;
protected HtmlInputHelperDatePicker datePicker;
protected HtmlInputHelperDatePicker getDatePicker() {
        if (datePicker == null) {
            datePicker = (HtmlInputHelperDatePicker) findComponentInRoot("datePicker");
        }
        return datePicker;
```

*JSP* part:

```
<TD align="left" width="438"><h:inputText
    styleClass="inputText" id="actualDate"
    value="#{announcementInfoBean.announcementDetail.actual_announcement_date}">
    <hx:inputHelperDatePicker />
    <hx:validateDateTimeRange
        minimum="1978/03/01" maximum="#{sessionScope.userSession.systemDate}" />
    <f:convertDateTime  pattern="MMM-dd-yyyy" />
    </h:inputText><BR>
    <h:message styleClass="message" id="message_actualDate"
        for="actualDate"></h:message></TD>
```

Does anyone how to fix this?